# O que significa a expressão "a bruxa que é cega esbarra na gente e a vida estanca"?

Tags: significado-em-contexto, interpretação, letras-de-músicas, música

A música [A Banca do Distinto](https://www.letras.mus.br/elis-regina/424055/) fala da percepção de superioridade por questões socioeconômicas, e diz que todos são iguais no final, morrendo. Mesmo que a música seja simples no geral, esta parte não consegui entender, nem achar ninguém que entendesse:

> A bruxa que é cega esbarra na gente e a vida estanca

O que significaria esta parte da música?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro:

> O infortúnio, que é imprevisível, nos atinge [a todos], e morremos.

A parte "a vida estanca" é clara: a vida cessa, "deixa de fluir", ou seja: "a gente morre".

E "bruxa" aqui deve significar, quando não a própria morte, "infortúnio", "desgraça", como na conhecida [expressão](https://www.aulete.com.br/bruxa):

> **A(s) bruxa(s) está (estão) solta(s)**
> **1** Referência a época ou situação em que se sucedem tragédias, acidentes, infortúnios etc.

Sobre ela ser cega, similarmente à expressão "a justiça é cega", indica que o infortúnio atinge as pessoas indiscriminadamente — e também de modo imprevisível, como enfatizado pela conotação acidental de "esbarrar".

Comment: Faz bastante sentido, Stfusa. Obrigado.